# Error Creating Bean Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I am in the process of creating a portal using spring 4.2.4 and hibernate 4.2.21 Final using maven. I am facing the following exception. I couldn't figure out what mistake am making. I am not using any hibernate.cfg.xml as am making the configuration details inside dispatcher servlet. Also in the error stack trace it shows, it could not find the path of model. Jars i have added through maven is displayed in below picture.

[image: Jars i have added through maven]

This is the directory structure of my application

[image: Folder Structure]

As in the folder structure, there is employee.java as model. I am not finding where i have made mistake.

Exception

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet hr-servlet threw exception


type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet hr-servlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet hr-servlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/hr-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory could not be successfully initialized. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsuccessfulInit
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory could not be successfully initialized. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsuccessfulInit
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:276)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:242)
    org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:255)
    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.XMLContext.<init>(XMLContext.java:47)
    org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(JPAMetadataProvider.java:29)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.createReflectionManager(Configuration.java:2505)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:286)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:277)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:281)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<init>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:140)
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:343)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my dispatcher servlet.

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.is.employeeportal.controller" />
<!-- <context:property-placeholder location="com.is.employeeportal.model" /> -->
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
 <property name="prefix">
   <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
 </property>
 <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
 </property>
 </bean>
 <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/port_dev" />
        <property name="username" value="port_dev" />
        <property name="password" value="port_dev_123" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">


        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.is.employeeportal.model.Employee</value>             
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>                
            </props>
        </property>


    </bean>
    <bean id="employeeDAO" class="com.is.employeeportal.dao.EmployeeDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
<!--    <bean id="hrController" class="com.is.employeeportal.controller.HrController"> -->
<!--    </bean> -->
</beans>
```

Can anybody enlighten me where i am making the mistake? I have stuck down with this issue for hours.

Comment: you have slf4j-api.jar file. I don't think you have fully configured it. Can you remove that jar file and try.

Answer (score 0):

SLF4J is only an interface for logging. You need an implementation.
Log4j is a common choice, but [there are some others](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.fr/2013/08/how-to-configure-slf4j-with-different.html).

If you are using slf4j with log4j, you can use a `log4j.properties` file, with the content below :

```
# Global logging configuration (Options DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, OFF)
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,stdout,fichier,spring
# mail à ajouter pour que les emails d'alerte sur erreur soient envoyés


# Console output...
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %x - %m%n
#log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] - %m%n

log4j.appender.fichier=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fichier.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.fichier.File=/var/log/tomcat/spring-web-mvc-json.log
log4j.appender.fichier.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fichier.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.fichier.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.fichier.MaxBackupIndex=10

log4j.appender.spring=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fichier.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.spring.File=/var/log/tomcat/spring-details.log
log4j.appender.spring.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.spring.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.spring.MaxFileSize=5000KB
log4j.appender.spring.MaxBackupIndex=10

# configuration...
org.apache.commons.digester.Digester=INFO

# specific packages coded by myself...
com.bendathierry.spring.web.mvc=DEBUG,fichier

# springframework 3.1.xx packages to log...
org.springframework=DEBUG,spring
org.springframework.beans=DEBUG,spring
org.springframework.security=DEBUG,spring
org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults=DEBUG,spring
org.springframework.jdbc.core=DEBUG,spring
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager=DEBUG,spring
#org.springframework.core=DEBUG
#org.springframework.util=DEBUG
#org.springframework.context=DEBUG
#org.springframework.remoting=DEBUG
#org.springframework.jndi=DEBUG
#org.springframework.http=DEBUG
#org.springframework.web=DEBUG
#org.springframework.scheduling=DEBUG
#org.springframework.scripting=DEBUG
#org.springframework.validation=DEBUG
#org.springframework.mail=DEBUG
#org.springframework.ui=DEBUG
#org.springframework.expression=DEBUG
```

I think it could help you to create these file with the content given :)